# Fake German postwar hospital to trick allied soldier into revealing secrets

Tags: identify-this-movie

I would like to identify a probable 70's movie about a captured allied soldier. The German captors set up a fake hospital away from the city, complete with ingenious and very convincing details. The prisoner keeps some important military secret his captors covet, and when he wakes up he is told that the war is over and the Germans won, that he was hurt and has amnesia, and that he should rest and be released when fully recovered. Meanwhile they try to get him to reveal the secret claiming it no longer matters since the war is over. The soldier almost falls for it, but in the end he notices a small but troublesome paper cut hidden in a fold in his finger, and therefore not found when his captors painstakingly inspected his body for recent wounds. The cut is obviously recent and he remembers how it came about, thus proving the whole thing is a charade and the secret is not revealed.

UPDATE: Solved, it's "36 Hours".

Comment: Interestingly the plot was reused in the Prisoner with Patrick Magoohan, except it was a blackened fingernail which alerted him that the timeframe was incorrect.  Must see if I can find out what it was called...

Comment: It's "schizoid man", instead of trying to convince him of passing time, they try to convince him he isn't the real no6, using aversion therapy to make home left handed etc, only when he remembers the injury is he able to overcome the programming and avoid revealing his secret.

Comment: This is also similar (at a high level) to the plot of Roald Dahl's short story, *Beware of the Dog*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The movie you're looking for is most probably [*36 Hours*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057809/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_74) from 1965. It stars *James Garner* as an Allied officer captured shortly before D-Day. The Germans stage a play for him pretending that he was in coma and meanwhile the Allies have won, to trick him into revealing the supposedly successful Allied attack plans.

> In this psychological war-drama an Army Major is captured by the
>   Germans during World War II. They attempt to brainwash him into
>   believing the war is over and that he is safe in an Allied hospital,
>   so that he will divulge Allied invasion plans.

I even think to remember this clue with the small cut wound that makes him realize the fraud.

Comment: Wow, that is probably it. Watched the trailer on youtube -- amazing how different things look 40 years later. Now will see the whole thing to verify the papercut thing. Also I misremembered the time elapsed: instead of 36 hours I thought several weeks. Also I wrongly remembered an openly German hospital -- maybe I subconsciously dismissed the possibility so many Germans, nurses, doctors could successfully disguise their true identity at close interaction for weeks on end. From another movie I thought they could briefly fake Americanness unless they were asked who won the World Series.

Comment: @Mayavimmer I think it was also presented as a German hospital to *James Garner*, but in supposedly post-war occupied Germany.

Comment: Couple things: 1. I remembered the battle of wits lasting much longer, but the ploy was discovered within the first hour. The rest of the movie is just an escape from camp movie. 2. Shultz! From Hogan's Heroes! Recycled as is!

Answer (score 6):

Is it [36 Hours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36_Hours), From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057809/)

> Germans kidnap an American major and try to convince him that World
>   War II is over, so that they can get details about the Allied invasion
>   of Europe out of him.